# FLEX - Paper Layout

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, layout, text

How can I get the `RichEditableText` control to display the text in pages. Just like in Microsoft Word, it should have visual pagebreaks which are determined by a page-size setting so that, I can switch to A4, US Letter size, etc and the text will flow into vertical rectangles (pages) accordingly.

[image]

I sense I should use the **Text Layout Framework**, `TextFlow` actually. 
But what is the starting point and what should I focus on, in order to get this paper layout.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with the default `RichEditableText` component, but here's a little snippet that should get you started:

```
<s:VGroup gap="20">
    <mx:UIComponent id="page1" width="50" height="50" />
    <mx:UIComponent id="page2" width="50" height="50" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Replace the sizes with your A4 or other sizes. If you want the number of pages to be dynamic, you'll have to use a `DataGroup` instead.

Now we create one `TextFlow` object, we assign it one [ContainerController](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/container/ContainerController.html) per page, and we have it lay out the text over our pages:

```
var tlf:TextFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString(
    "Some very long text that spans many pages goes in here."
);
for each (var page:Sprite in [page1, page2]) {
    var c:ContainerController = new ContainerController(
        page, page.width, page.height
    );
    tlf.flowComposer.addController(c);
}
tlf.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

Comment: I think I'll go with a similar approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you will master [Text Layout Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tlf.adobe/files/3.0/current/textLayout_build.zip/download), you will be able to do even something like [this](http://switch.dl.sourceforge.net/project/tlf.adobe/3.0/current/Flow.swf) .

[Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tlf.adobe/files/3.0/current/samples.zip/download) you have many samples of using TLF, it includes pagination. This is the best starting point I think.

Comment: The pagination example is not what I'm looking for but thanks for pointing out the library. It helped a lot.